# String concatenation is not working properly

Tags: vb.net, string

I am facing a really very interesting problem with string.

My code is:

```
Dim stropt As String

stropt = " -i ""C:\Rajesh Prj\Video splitter\testvideo.wmv"" -start 00:00:00 -duration 00:00:10 -start 00:00:10 -duration 00:00:10 -sep -o short{000}.wmv"
'Dim strwithpara As String
'strwithpara = " -i """ + filepath + """ -start 00:00:00 -duration 00:00:10 -start 00:00:10 -duration 00:00:10 -sep -o short{000}.wmv"

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory() + "\asfbin.exe", stropt)
```

with above code its working fine, but when I uncomment the middle two lines, its giving me :

```
error: The system cannot find the file specified
```

even though I am not using variable `strwithpara` but its generating that error in `Process.Start`.

But when I comment those lines (which are uncommented in code above) its working fine.
Please tell me what I am missing and also suggest to me what should I do to resolve it.

I am taking value in `filepath` variable from file dialog's `FileName` property.

EDIT: I have also compared the values of variable `stropt` and `strwithpara` with "IF" condition and found those are same.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. It works just fine for me with both of the middle lines uncommented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of  `Environment.CurrentDirectory() + "\asfbin.exe"` and `stropt` using breakpoints and see if they match what you expect

Comment: its working fine when my above 2 commented are commented but when i make them uncommented than its showing error. and i am not using that with process so, i am not able to find the relation between them

Comment: @Rajesh - Its got to be something to do with the filepath variable?